# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with NSDictionary/CFDictionaryRef

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, exc-bad-access

I've got the following piece of code : (it's long)

```
//declarations (in the header) :
NSDictionary* batteryRawDict;
@property (strong, atomic, readonly) NSDictionary* batteryReport; //this dictionary is, obviously, @synthesize'd


case PFSKGroupBattery: { //to get more informations or to subscribe for events about power sources, use the IOPowerSources API
        if (!firstRunDoneForBattery) {
            batEntry = IOServiceGetMatchingService(masterPort, IOServiceMatching("IOPMPowerSource"));
            if (batEntry == 0) {
                _error = PFSKReturnComponentUnavailable;
                return false;
            }
        }
        CFMutableDictionaryRef  batProps = NULL;
        result = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(batEntry, &batProps, NULL, 0);
        if (result!=kIOReturnSuccess) {
            _error = PFSKReturnIOKitCFFailure;
            _extError = result;
            return false;
        } else {
            batteryRawDict = (__bridge NSDictionary*)batProps;
            CFRelease(batProps);
            NSMutableDictionary* temp = [NSMutableDictionary.alloc init];
            if (!firstRunDoneForBattery) { //static keys
                //[temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"DesignCapacity"] forKey:@"DesignedCapacity"];
                [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"DesignCycleCount9C"] forKey:@"DesignedCycleCount"];
                [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"BatterySerialNumber"] forKey:@"Serial"];
                [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"DeviceName"] forKey:@"Model"];
                [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"Manufacturer"] forKey:@"Manufacturer"];
                unsigned int manufactureDateAsInt = [[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"ManufactureDate"] intValue];
                NSDateComponents* manufactureDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
                manufactureDateComponents.year = (manufactureDateAsInt >> 9) + 1980;
                manufactureDateComponents.month = (manufactureDateAsInt >> 5) & 0xF;
                manufactureDateComponents.day = manufactureDateAsInt & 0x1F;
                [temp setObject:[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:manufactureDateComponents] forKey:@"ManufactureDate"];
                firstRunDoneForBattery = 1;
            }
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"BatteryInstalled"] forKey:@"isPresent"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"FullyCharged"] forKey:@"isFull"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"IsCharging"] forKey:@"isCharging"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"ExternalConnected"] forKey:@"isACConnected"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"Amperage"] forKey:@"Amperage"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"CurrentCapacity"] forKey:@"CurrentCapacity"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"MaxCapacity"] forKey:@"MaxCapacity"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"Voltage"] forKey:@"Voltage"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"CycleCount"] forKey:@"CycleCount"];
            [temp setObject:@(([[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"MaxCapacity"] intValue] / [[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"DesignCapacity"] intValue])*100) forKey:@"Health"]; //percentage
            [temp setObject:@([[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"Temperature"] doubleValue] / 100) forKey:@"Temperature"];
            /*to be checked*/[temp setObject:@([[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"Amperage"] doubleValue] / 1000 * [[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"Voltage"] doubleValue] / 1000) forKey:@"Power"];
            NSDateComponents* differenceDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                            fromDate:[temp objectForKey:@"ManufactureDate"]
                                              toDate:[NSDate date]
                                             options:0];
            [temp setObject:@([differenceDate day]) forKey:@"Age"];
            batteryReport = [temp copy];
            NSLog(@"-----------------------awesome debugging code-----------");
        }
        CFRelease(batProps);
        break;
    }
```

Randomly (= not each time), when control reaches this case, an error will happen (either EXC_BAD_ACCESS or EXC_I386_GPFLT), that will, respectively, be located by xCode on `batteryRawDict = (__bridge NSDictionary*)batProps;` or on the @implementation line.

Any idea on why this is happening ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like bad memory management.

You call `CFRelease` on `batProps` after bridging the pointer to an `NSDictionary`. This leaves `batteryRawDict` pointing to garbage.

I suggest you change these two lines:

```
batteryRawDict = (__bridge NSDictionary*)batProps;
CFRelease(batProps);
```

to:

```
batteryRawDict = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)batProps;
```

If you are using ARC then you are done. If you are using MRC then add a call to `[batteryRawDict release];` at an appropriate point.

You also have a second call to `CGRelease(batProps);` at the end of the `case` statement. That's a problem too. Don't over release pointers.

Run the Analyzer on the code too. That should point out these issues.

Comment: First thing, thanks ! I'll mark your answer as soon as I run the analyzer. Apart from that, what's the point of __bridge_transfer ?

Comment: The `__bridge_transfer` does what the name implies. It transfers ownership of the object memory from the old variable to the new variable. So instead of needing to release `batProps` you now need to release `batteryRawDict`. And that will be handled for you by ARC.

Comment: Okay, thanks, your tips solved the EXC_xxx ! However, this doesn't fix the code loop... so my code still gets executed twice (just before the ```break``` statement).

Comment: You don't provide any useful info to solve your "looping" issue. I would suggest updating this question so it focuses on just the memory issue. With that solved, post another question specific to the "looping" issue (the two have nothing to do with each other so they are completely separate questions). In the new question, be sure to provide more context relevant to the looping.